# To write the response of servlet into pdf using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, servlets, pdf

I am trying to hit a url through URL Connection in servlet. The response of the request (which is a pdf) needs to be displayed on the browser as pdf. Here I do not have any temporary pdf file kept on the server which means i want my code to generate the url response as a pdf on the fly. Currently my webservice returns pdf if I hit the webservice url(REST) directly in the browser.
Here is my code
I am getting a blank output

code:

```
package com.mm;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ "dummy" + "\"");


byte[] pdfData = servicecall().getBytes("UTF-8");


System.out.println(pdfData.length);
response.setContentLength(pdfData.length);
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
output.write(pdfData);
output.flush();
output.close();


}




public String servicecall()
{
String output = "";
BufferedReader reader = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;


try
{


URL url = new URL("http://hardik/Wecs/External/private/document.aspx?prd=1042737~~PDF~~MTR~~IPDS~~EN~~2014-01-10%2014:00:41~~SOLEST%20120~~");   
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/pdf");
conn.connect();


if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
+ conn.getResponseCode());
}


reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
(conn.getInputStream())));




stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
}
output = stringBuilder.toString();


} catch (MalformedURLException e) {


e.printStackTrace();


} catch (IOException e) {


e.printStackTrace();


}


finally {
try {
reader.close();


} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
System.out.println( output);
return output;
}


}
```

I get a blank pdf output

Comment: do u get some bytes of data?

Comment: Yes am printing the bytes of data on the tomcat console. but the same result if am trying to put into pdf by setting 'application/pdf' i get a blank output

Comment: Hope you are closing your file stream

Comment: Hi Juned,I am not using filestream. I am using outputstream

Comment: Is the Binary Data BASE64 encoded ? , I don't believe you will be able to treat the binary as a string without a bunch of errors

Comment: More infomation is required. You need to post client side code showing what you are doing with the data.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to resolve this issue? We are having the exact same problem. Would be glad if you can get us the working code. Thanks!